# Deploying Nx workspace to Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, nrwl-nx, nrwl

My Nx app works fine locally but when deployed to GAE it fails with this error:

`sh: 1: exec: nx: not found`

It can't find `nx` which is listed under `dependencies` (not `devDependencies`) since GAE doesn't install those.

My `package.json` has this in it:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve api",
```

so when GAE runs `npm run start` it fails. I tried specifying the path directly to `nx` but trying to refer to it using `node_modules/nx/bin/nx` but that fails too.

I'm wondering how I can get GAE to use `nx` to serve the app.

This is such a simple and basic used case that I'm confounded that it doesn't have a straightforward solution. I must be missing something very simple.

Comment: Have you tried executing `npx nx serve api` instead of just using `nx serve`?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Nx@13, here are steps to deploy to GAE:

1. Add  `"generatePackageJson": true,` to `production`  executor, it will generate a `package.json` in `dist/apps/serviceA/package.json`
2. [GAE will look for](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#application_startup) `scripts:{"start:"your way to start nodejs app "}` or `server.js` if the `start` script not found. You will have to write a script to add `scripts:{"start:"node main.js"}` into the generated `package.json` in #1
3. In `cloudbuild` we will have to execute GAE deploy command in `dist/apps/serviceA` folder, luckily `cloudbuild` [step supports](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema) `dir`

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: node:16-bullseye
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['install']

  - name: node:16-bullseye
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['run', 'lint', '${_SERVICE_NAME}']

  - name: node:16-bullseye
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['run', 'test', '${_SERVICE_NAME}']

  - name: node:16-bullseye
    entrypoint: npm
    args:
      ['run', 'build', '${_SERVICE_NAME}', '--', '--configuration=production']

  - name: node:16-bullseye
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      [
        '-c',
        'node tools/prepare-gcp-app-engine.js --serviceName=${_SERVICE_NAME}',
      ]

  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:376.0.0-slim
    dir: dist/apps/${_SERVICE_NAME}
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - app
      - deploy
      - app-engine.yaml
      - --version=$SHORT_SHA
      - --promote
      - --stop-previous-version
      - --quiet

substitutions:
  _SERVICE_NAME: game-api
```

[Source code demo](https://github.com/coinconket/conketkemon/commit/bbbf2b82a05fb270e3e0b02c9888bfcd4e0a8ec8)

Comment: I know it's been a while but could could you elaborate a bit on this? In the **gcloud deploy** step you are pointing to an app-engine.yaml file which doesn't seem to exist in the current directory (`dist/apps/game-api`) and, also, the actual app-engine.yaml file in the repository seems to be a cloud build file, not an app engine app.yaml file

Comment: I did not recall correctly, I think we have a dist, if you want to copy a GAE config file from `src` to `dist`, simply edit this part of the build config: https://github.com/coinconket/conketkemon/blob/master/apps/game-api/project.json#L13

Comment: Thanks, this helped clear up some confusion. I did manage to solved it by moving the app.yaml file to the right location