# Deploy NX applications to Google AppEngine using gcloud app deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, nrwl-nx

**Problem**

I have an NX repository with multiple applications that I am able to build & start successfully locally. I'm now looking to deploy these applications to Google AppEngine.

In the future I will be looking at implementing this through GitHub Actions but for the moment I was just looking at deploying directly from my local machine using `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --quiet`. In other (non NX) repositories, I'm able to do this easily, but I'm having trouble with the best approach to use within an NX workspace.

I've played around with trying to deploy an app from the apps folder using an project target e.g. `nx run api-one:deploy` and also from the root of the application using an npm target `npm run deploy:api-two`.

**Error**

- Deploying using nx project target (`nx run api-one:deploy`)

I get the error `Service Unavailable` when trying to access the deployed app and in the logs I get saying `Cannot find package 'express' imported from /workspace/dist/main.js`

- Deploying using npm target (`npm run deploy:api-two`)

I get the error `Service Unavailable` when trying to access the deployed app and in the logs I get saying `/workspace/dist/apps/api-two/main.js`

**Question**

How can I deploy a single application in my nx workspace to Google AppEngine using the command `gcloud app deploy ...`

---

**Code**

A Sample Repository containing the code outlined below can be found [here](https://github.com/b-simpson12/nx-gcp-deploy).

The code structure looks something like this

```
nx-workspace
|
 --apps
 |
  -- api-one
   -- src
    -- main.ts
    -- ...
   -- package.json
   -- project.json
   -- app.yaml
   ....
  -- api-two
   -- src
    -- main.ts
    -- ...
   -- package.json
   -- project.json
   -- app.yaml
   ....
 -- dist
  -- apps
   -- api-one
    -- main.js
    -- ...
   -- api-two 
    -- main.js
    -- ...
 ...
 package.json
 ...
```

**api-one package.json**

```
{
  "name": "api-one",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/apps/api-one/main.js",
    "gcp-build": ""
  }
}
```

**api-one project.json**

```
...
"build": {
  "executor": "@nx/esbuild:esbuild",
  "options": {
    "main": "apps/api-one/src/main.ts",
    "tsConfig": "apps/api-one/tsconfig.app.json",
    "outputPath": "dist/apps/api-one"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "prod": {
      "optimization": false,
      "generatePackageJson": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "inspect": false
    }
  }
},
"deploy": {
  "executor": "nx:run-commands",
  "dependsOn": [
    "^build:prod"
  ],
  "defaultConfiguration": "dev",
  "options": {
    "cwd": "apps/api-one",
    "parallel": false
  },
  "configurations": {
    "dev": {
      "command": "gcloud app deploy app.yaml --quiet"
    }
  }
},
...
```

**api-one app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs18

instance_class: F1

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: public/static
    expiration: 30d
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

**root package.json**

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/apps/api-two/main.js",
    "gcp-build": "",
    "deploy:app-one": "gcloud app deploy ./apps/api-two/app.yaml --quiet"
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Can you try deploying your NX application by following the steps suggested in this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71830995/18265702).

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni, thanks for responding. 

I had seen that post but the answer didn't seem to make much sense to me. I would prefer not to use cloud build but I tried to manually run the steps. The example **cloudbuild.yaml** file doesn't exist in the repository. Instead, it is called app-engine.yaml. None of the npm targets in the app-engine.yaml file seem to exist and the final `gcloud app deploy...` seems to refer to the cloud build config and not a normal app.yaml file. 

I tried to manually reproduce it fixing some of the issues above but I still can't deploy a working app.